# Parse string to be number or number and percent symbol

Tags: c++, string, parsing

In C++, better without Boost library, how to make sure that the std::string str contains either a number or a number followed by '%' sign? If it does not belong to these two cases an error should be issued.

Comment: Tried to ask for a solution to see lots of variants, learn and choose the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctype.h>
bool is_a_bad_char(char c) {
  return !(isdigit(c) || (c=='%'));
}

int main() {
  std::string str = "123123%4141219";
  if (std::find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), is_a_bad_char) != str.end()) {
    std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is probably to convert the string (using `strtol`
or `strtod`, depending on what type of number you expect), then look at
the following character.  Something like:

(EDITED to correct error handling):

```
bool
isNumberOrPercent( std::string const& value )
{
    char const* end;
    errno = 0;
    strtod( value.c_str(), &end );
    return errno == 0 
        && (*end = '%' ? end + 1 : end) - value.c_str() == value.size();
}
```

Comment: Note also that `strtod` isn't *required* to set `errno` in the case where conversion fails (although it is for over/underflow). So annoyingly, your function could end up returning true when passed an empty string.

Comment: Ouch.  That's a serious error in the standard (IMHO).  (I couldn't believe the standard had done something that stupid when I read what you wrote, but apparently it has.)  So I do need an additional test for `end == value.c_str()`.

Comment: I agree with YHO! `strtod` has two ways of indicating a problem during the conversion, neither of which covers all error cases (if overflow is considered an error). This is weak.

Answer (score 0):

1. `find_first_not_of` with all the digits and `%`
2. If the above returns `npos`, then check the last character is `%`.

Answer (score 0):

Not very C++-ish, but something like this would do it:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

bool checkformat(const std::string &s) {
    const char *begin = s.c_str();
    char *end;
    double val = std::strtod(begin, &end);
    if (end == begin) return false;
    if (*end == '%') ++end;
    return (end - begin == s.size());
}
```

Be aware that `strtod` skips initial whitespace, so if you don't want to accept a string with initial whitespace then you'd need to separately reject that. It also accepts `"NAN"`, `"INF"`, `"INFINITY"` (all case-insensitive), and each of those things preceded by `+` or `-`, and in the case of `"NAN"` optionally followed some implementation-defined characters to indicate *which* NaN value it represents. Arguably "INF" is a number, but by definition "NAN" isn't, so you'd want to return false if `val != val` and possibly also check for infinities.

[Edit: I think I've fixed the issues James raises below, except that `" "` and `" %"` are still in dispute. And then he added overflow to the mix. Between his answer and mine, you should get the idea -- first decide how you want to treat each edge case, then code it.]

Comment: What about the case where the initial string was something like "1\0x"?  I'd check that `*pend - begin == s.size()` (after incrementing if `**pend == '%'`).  And neither your code nor mine handle something like `"   "` or `"   %"` correctly; I think you have to set `errno` to `0`, then test after, for that.

Comment: Also, I think you've got a bug in the code: you want `char *pend;`, and to pass `&pend` to `strtod` (and replace all of the other uses of `*pend` with simply `pend`, and `**pend` with `*pend`).  Plus the typo with `s&` instead of `&s` in the parameter.

Comment: @James: agreed about embedded nuls. `strtod` is supposed to store its paramter `str` to `*endptr` if no conversion takes place, not a pointer to the first character of the subject sequence, so what's the problem with `" "`? `*pend` will be `' '`, I'll return `false`. I should probably have tested this.

Comment: I wasn't sure about what ends up in `pend` if there's no conversion.  I thought it was the address passed as an argument, but I couldn't find it in the standard text.

Comment: There's also the question about what the function should do if the input is something like "1.0E1000000".  Checking for `errno` after `stdtod` will return `false`; checking on whether `strtod` has consumed the entire string will return `true`.  (Which is correct, of course, depends on how you define what the function should do.)

Comment: @James: I was looking at Opengroup, so to be fair if Posix has messed up and contradicted the standard, then I'm wrong. And I agree that overflow could go either way for this function - the question doesn't specify. Plus it may turn out that the questioner's definition of "a number" doesn't really correspond with `strtod`'s definition, which is approximately "a valid double literal".